# Odd character appending to the front of python list

Tags: python

I'm having an issue with regards to running python on linux. I'm trying to learn python and wanted to try and parse a small XML file and put the tags and data into the list. But every time I run the code I get a 'u' appending to each element in the list.

```
[u'world']
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'world': [u'data']})
```

My code is as follows:

```
import xml.sax

from collections import defaultdict

class TransformXML(xml.sax.ContentHandler):

def __init__ (self):
    self.start_tag_name = -1
    self.tag_data = -1
    self.myDict = defaultdict(list)
    self.tags = []

def startElement(self, name, attrs):
    self.start_tag_name = name
    print name
    print self.start_tag_name

def characters(self, content):
    if content.strip(' \r\n\t') != "":
        self.tag_data = content.strip(' \r\n\t')
        print self.start_tag_name
        self.tags.append(self.start_tag_name)
        self.myDict[self.start_tag_name].append(content.strip(' \r\n\t'))

def endElement(self, name):
    pass

def __del__ (self):
    if self.myDict:
        del self.myDict
        print "deleteing myDict"
```

Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: It means the string is `unicode` encoded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That 'weird' symbol basically means that the `string` or `character` is encoded in unicode

Eg. If i have a string `Test`:

```
>>> unicode('Test')
u'Test'
>>> s = unicode('Test')
>>> type(s)
<type 'unicode'>
```

Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)

To sum up, according to the `python` docs,

> ...a Unicode string is a sequence of code points, which are numbers from
>   0 to 0x10ffff. This sequence needs to be represented as a set of bytes
>   (meaning, values from 0-255) in memory. The rules for translating a
>   Unicode string into a sequence of bytes are called an encoding.